# How to create SAS data set extracting observations with unique keys

Tags: sql, sas

I have a `sas` data set consisting of more than 100 variables. Variables `pid` - a character variable and `year` -  a numeric variable identify observations in the data set.

How can I create a new data set consisting of observations that have unique `pid` and `year` combination. That is, if a given `pid` and `year` combination occurs more than once, I want to delete all the associated observations, not just the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use much of data step. I use proc sql and is easy for me.

```
proc sql;
    create table new_dataset as
    select * from old_dataset as a
      join
    (select pid, year, count(1) from old_dataset group by pid, year having count(1)<2)
    as b on a.pid=b.pid and a.year=b.year;
run;
```

inner query only gets pid and year which occur once. Any multiple occurrence of pid and year are not taken into account because of `having count(1)<2`. I get those observations only from original by joining back on pid and year. This actually doesn't need sorting.

Let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: While you don't explicitly code a sort step, SQL may be performing a sort in the background (unless it can perform the join entirely in memory in a Hash table, but you can't control how it will perform the join).

Answer (score 2):

Simple use of `first.` and `last.` in a data step will do this.  Run `proc sort` if the data is not already sorted by pid and year.

```
proc sort data=have;
by pid year;
run;

data want;
set have;
by pid year;
if first.year and last.year then output; /* only keep unique rows */
run;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - the asker wants to delete all rows with a combination of pid and year that comes up more than once, not just the duplicates.

Comment: @user667489 I believe it would. If a record as first.year AND last.year it would not have any duplicates.

Comment: @user667489 This is the gold standard method (before UNIQUEOUT anyway) of doing this in SAS.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNIQUEOUT and NOUNIQUEKEY option in proc sort for a single step solution.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
run;

proc sort data=class nouniquekey uniqueout=unique_data;
by sex age;
run;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0qh2iuz3fa6rpn1eib1gaxr0sb5.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a dataset containing combinations of pid and year that appear more than once, then merge it with the rest to remove matches:

```
proc sort data = have nodupkey dupout = duplicates;
    by pid year;
run;

data want;
    merge have 
          duplicates(in = a keep = pid year);
    by pid year;
    if not(a);
run;
```

Comment: There's also the UNIQUEOUT option as of SAS 9.3+

Comment: @Reeza That sounds like an answer :)